# Rails hash null check - which is better 'if-condition' and 'ternary operator'?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, null-check

I have below hash

```
instance_options[:param_page]
instance_options[:param_page][:comment_page]
instance_options[:param_page][:comment_per]
```

I need comment_page, comment_per value
I did refactoring code
But I not sure what is best hash null check
let me know best null check if you know anothers

befor

```
comment_page = 1
comment_per = 0
param_page = instance_options[:param_page]
if param_page
  comment_page = param_page[:comment_page].presence || comment_page
  comment_per = param_page[:comment_per].presence || comment_per
end
```

after

```
comment_page = instance_options[:param_page][:comment_page].present? ? instance_options[:param_page][:comment_page] : 1
comment_per = instance_options[:param_page][:comment_per].present? ? instance_options[:param_page][:comment_per] : 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You go a step further:

```
comment_page = instance_options.dig(:param_page, :comment_page).presence || 1
comment_per  = instance_options.dig(:param_page, :comment_per).presence || 0
```

That will go digging into `instance_options` twice but the cost will be trivial. If you need to worry about types (say the `:comment_page` value could be a string), then you could add `#to_i` calls:

```
comment_page = (instance_options.dig(:param_page, :comment_page).presence || 1).to_i
comment_per  = (instance_options.dig(:param_page, :comment_per).presence || 0).to_i
```

Or use [`reverse_merge`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-reverse_merge) (since that's for setting defaults):

```
param_page = instance_options[:param_page] || {}
param_page.reverse_merge(comment_page: 1, comment_per: 0)
# Then use param_page[:comment_page] and param_page[:comment_per] instead of two locals
```

Comment: `reverse_merge` is aliased as `with_defaults` so this exactly the sort of thing it is for. I use the `presence` technique (and `#to_a`, `#to_h`, `#to_i`, ...) all the time to "hide" `nil` checks.

Comment: I changed code to ```post_page = instance_options.dig(:pagaination_param, :post_page).presence.to_i || 1``` and added to_i because post_page type not be int. i got such a type error

Comment: yes. i did read https://apidock.com/rails/Object/presence but value of ```nil.to_i``` is 0. it's can't be null check. then should i change code your comment of ```post_page = (instance_options.dig(:pagaination_param, :post_page).presence || 1).to_i``` ? ```instance_options.dig(:pagaination_param, :post_page).to_i.presence || 1``` is correct? because ```to_i``` chage nil to 0

Comment: i think 0 is not nil and i did run console ```$ rails c```  ```0.presence == nil
=> false ``` i got false. i think ```...to_i.presence``` is incorrect

Comment: @ChangwooRhee Right, sorry, getting myself confused. I think you'd want `comment_page = (instance_options.dig(:param_page, :comment_page).presence || 1).to_i` if you want to always get an integer back.